# PHP using exit()

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

I am using Cakephp but this is a MVC/php doubt

```
letting the view display the message
```

vs

```
echo 'Invalid Data'; exit;
```

I would like to know is there any pitfalls in the second case like memory leak etc.. Which one is better

**EDIT**

In case of a ajax call is exit good. and what about memory leak and other issues . Are all variables deallocated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a custom ExceptionHandler (set_error_handler / set_exception_handler) and throw an Exception if you encounter any errors (CakePHP should already provide an ExceptionHandler). Make some space in your view and if the ExceptionHandler/ErrorHandler has a message, show it there to let the user know.

Your second code will just produce a blank page containing the little text. Every user will appreciate if you show the message inside your usual page layout instead of producing a blank page (which looks broken to most people).

Comment: +1 deleted my answer in favor of yours since yours was a few seconds first and my answer didnt add any significantly new.

Answer (score 3):

The Cake tools to signal errors to the user are session messages and error views.

For "passive" actions like view actions, you should throw a 404 or similar, possibly more specialized error, e.g. if the requested model does not exist:

```
function view($id) {
    $data = $this->Model->read(null, $id);
    if (!$data) {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }

    ...
}
```

See [Error Handling with CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1188/Error-Handling).

For any POST action, you should return the user to the view and display an error message using  `$this->Session->setFlash('Error!')` and appropriate error messages for each invalid form field. That's the default behavior of baked views and controllers.

Terminating the whole script with `exit` makes for a miserable user experience.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid `exit`. `Exit` is an *abnormal* termination, and programs should not terminate abnormally. Even if an error occurs, there are still many things that needs to be done - cleanup, logging, notifying the user etc. After all, your operating system doesn't reboot every time it cannot open a file.

Comment: It's not abnormal. An abnormal termination would be a fatal error or uncatched exception. (I just found out that you can do exit("Invalid data") - http://php.net/exit to terminate the script + print an error message. I'm scared now.)

Comment: -1 for abnormal and insinuating cleanup could not be done when using exit. Exit terminates the script with Shutdown functions and object destructors.

Comment: if the application needs `cleanup()`, you can do `register_shutdown_function(array($obj, 'cleanup')` so that's not an argument.

Answer (score 0):

**performance-wise**  (AJAX cals)

Use `exit()`.

---

**user experience-wise**  (standard site nav)

Show the error in a proper formated page keeping the user within your site.

Comment: Why use exit() on AJAX calls? He should rather return a JSON string containing a good error message to be displayed on the client side.

Comment: use exit on ajax calls for when nefarious types are calling you ajax page in a non ajax way, same as you would a normal page where you should halt execution after an error.

Comment: @halfdan my thoughts on exit() on AJAX run similar to those of Matt. Besides, as the user was asking what was more efficient within Cake, halt-stopping and moving along is more efficient than letting Cake finish gracefully.